# how to access to test class from another module to use in junit test?

Tags: android, junit4

I split current monolithic module to several modules: `:app`, `:ui`, `:base`.

I wrote test in `:ui` module using class from `:base` module.

```
class FooTest : BaseTest {

@Test
fun fooTest() {}
}
```

so `BaseTest` is in `:base` module but :ui module depends on `:base`. So AS shows to me that is is ok.

in gradle file for :ui module:

```
dependences {

   implementation project(":base")
}
```

But when test runs I get:

```
BaseTest: Unresolved reference: BaseTest
```

I tried to add:

```
   testImplementation project(":base")
```

or

```
   androidTestImplementation project(":base")
```

but not solve the problem. :(

Answer (score 1):

This works if the `BaseTest` file is in the `main` directory of :base instead of the `test` directory

For example, you can have a module called `commontest` that contains common utils/classes that contain these in the main directory of the module and then to use it in other modules you can include it with `testImplementation project(':commontest')`

Comment: Thx. Now I know why my tries do not work. do you know how to force the compiler to "see" the classes form test subfolder?

Comment: There might be a way to do it, but I couldn't find it.